# What is the graphical effect occurring to non-mipmapped distant textures called?

Tags: antialiasing, terminology, mipmaps

We all know about [mip-mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap). It reduces texture quality when a texture is further away.

Without mip-mapping, a texture appears to "flicker", like the top of the mountain here:

[image]

Is there any specific name for it?

I want to write a sentence like "I applied mip-mapping to solve the ___ effect", or "This is known as ___, and occurs when mip-mapping is not used".

Comment: Adding a screenshot of what you're talking about would greatly improve the question :)

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Thanks for the suggestion - Added. :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

What you're looking for is aliasing. It's little different from aliasing of hard 3d edges drawn on screen. Both come from rendering pixels too strictly, with one color or another. Antialiasing methods like mip-mapping only help blurring the edges so that intermediate colors are rendered. This can be applied to single textures but also to the whole screen.

Note however that mip-mapping is not the only solution to this. You can use other procedural interpolation algorithms too.

Comment: "Blurring the edges" is not a good way to describe what happens. This type of antialiasing is about using more samples from the original texture to determine the color of each pixel. Since mip-maps are smaller copies of the original texture, taking a single sample from a mip-map is like taking multiple samples from the original texture. It's also worth noting that mip-maps are only an optimization for rendering performance. You can get the same effect by taking more samples from the original texture when rendering.

Comment: @RogerDahl I've never heard of this "taking more samples from the original texture" to replace Mip-mapping. What is it called (so I can google it)?

Comment: @joehot200: "Mip-mapping" is just a pre-computation-based optimization for proper downscaling. In general if you're downscaling an image such that one output pixel corresponds to the space covered by N pixels in the source, you need to use at least those N pixels (and maybe more) as input. This is obviously computationally costly. By having pre-computed versions of the source at scales 2^-k for each reasonable value of k, you can cheat and essentially read N pixels all at once.

Comment: Of course it's actually a less-than-ideal approximation and yields some aliasing artifacts. What would be better than having pre-computed 2^-n scaled versions of the source texture would be having pre-computed band-limited versions of it still at full dimensions. This would get you correct sampling, but would of course consume a lot (probably prohibitive) more memory.

Comment: I know some games (especially slightly older ones) even have a slider labeled anti-aliasing.  So self-explanatory.

Comment: This is some case of Moiré - I'm surprised this answer doesn't mention it...

Comment: @Synxis Not really. Moiré is a special case of aliasing - this is an aliasing issue, but not a Moiré pattern. It's true the appearance is quite similar, though :)

Comment: @joehot200 There's many ways to reduce the sampling of textures *without* making precomputed mip-maps. They're not commonly used in real-time 3D graphics because they're much more expensive - mip-mapping is a technique optimized for speed. The simplest (still fast, but rather ugly) would be to reduce the texture coordinate precision - make sure that if you're far enough from the camera, your UV can only be integer multiples of 0.025 for example. It was used in early textured 3D games where memory was too big of an issue to allow even mip-mapping (and you used software rendering anyway).

Comment: @RogerDahl I like your explanation. It's simple yet precise. "Blurring the edges" is a really vague simplification indeed, but the OP seemed to know about mip-mapping and didn't ask for an explanation of it. Also, many blurring algorithms work similar to mip-mapping generation ;-)

Answer (score 13):

Aliasing artifacts/moiré patterns

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing

Comment: @joehot200 What do you mean, "related"? Aliasing is precisely what mipmapping solves, among other things. Aliasing *is* the "effect" that occurs.

Comment: The term "undersampling" arises here too, because your rendering is taking too few samples of the texture to accurately capture its average appearance over the span of the rendered pixel, so slight changes in sample points (eg. small camera moves) result in very different output values (shimmering/sparkling)

Answer (score 6):

> Is there any specific name for it?

That *flicker* you are talking about is called in this certain case **[moiré effect / pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern)**. It's a form of spatial aliasing as already mentioned in other answers. However, aliasing itself can result in a lot more things than just moiré patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard the term "popping and boiling" applied to the aliasing you're showing on that mountain in the background. It is not a mathematical term, but it is descriptive. So aliasing would be what you'd write your paper about if you wanted to invent a different fix for the problem and use it to get money (grants, academic promotion). "Popping and boiling" might be what you'd call it in a demo (for VC money).

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add that there's another side-effect of not using mip mapping: Not only will you get the hideous aliasing (see the [Nyquist theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) for what is going on), you will probably also get a reduction in performance as the texture accesses become incoherent and thrash the memory/cache system of your GPU.